# Gold Badge Design

Tags: feature-request, badges, design

Would it be possible to change the gold badge shape/style or something. I have a monitor that is really f-in bright and with the new white background badges, I have a hard time distinguishing gold and bronze badges.

[image]

Some of you may not have a problem telling the difference, but I'm getting old and decrepit! Also I bet some colorblind people would appreciate it too!

*whacks you with my cane for laughing when I said I was old and decrepit*

Comment: Please don't ask them to do things like this. We'll wake up tomorrow and the gold ones will sparkle.

Comment: You need a monitor that is less f-ing bright. :)

Comment: +1 That would be great (I know my eyes are uncommonly bad, so this might only benefit a few users)

Comment: @Tim Post: Unicorns?!! YAY!

Answer (score 6):

> Would it be possible to change the gold badge shape/style or something ...

Yes it is possible, but the site in question would need to propose a design on their Meta and, after discussion and voting, put forth a request to alter the sprites file.

For example:

- [Music.SE](https://music.stackexchange.com/) has three different badge types: ([Meta discussion](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2468/57957))

  [image: Music.SE Badges]
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) also has three different badge shapes: ([Meta discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/836/126327))

  [image: Graphic Design]
- [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) has two different shades on identical badges: ([Meta discussion](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2945/66746))

  [image: ELL.SE]
- [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) has different colors on identical badges: ([Meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/982/225622))

  [image: Arqade.SE]

Some sites, such as [Arts and Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/) or [Martial Arts](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/), sought beauty and clairity in simplicity.

Refer to the Meta discussions on the above sites to determine what goes into creating a design and putting forth a proposal to your community. If it is a popular idea you can put forth a request. There is a [Designer on staff](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/02/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) whom can assist or do it all.

See also our main Meta: "[Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/282094)". Some elements, such as badges, can be changed. Other things such as fonts or voting arrows must remain consistent across all the sites.

Comment: A user script to modify badges is available from https://stackapps.com/a/8117/54601