# Are there any plans to graduate any beta sites soon?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase, beta-sites, graduating-sites

It's been more than a year since a beta site was graduated – the latest being [Bitcoin in October 2017](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/876/congratulations-bitcoin-is-graduating). Since then, the SE team has been busy with the [rolling out of responsive design themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319274/responsive-design-themes-what-can-sites-customize-and-how-can-they-get-changes) which simplified theming across the SE network.

As mentioned before, beta sites that [consistently receive ten new questions every day will be considered for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites). With this criteria in mind, a quick search through Area 51 found that beta sites such as [Politics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics) and [Space Exploration](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration) currently consistently receive close to 10 questions / day and with mostly "Excellent" and "Good" for the other metrics.

So, seeing that the new theme is out on all sites, are there immediate plans to graduate some sites soon and which sites are they? If not, is there a rough timeline of when sites will be graduated?

Comment: I'm not sure if Politics will keep up after the Brexit and the end of the US shutdown...

Comment: @Glorfindel after Brexit? That's when the UK will try to make its relations with the EU seem like nothing ever happened. In the US, we still have Trump for another 3 years, and there are plenty of questions about what he's been doing and I'm sure they'll continue.

Comment: Sure, it's hard to predict the future. I've created a [graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/politics/query/969145/questions-per-day?fromDate=2018-01-01#graph) and you see the moving average has been 5-7 for a while and only recently a sudden spike.

Comment: Writing SE is [talking about exiting beta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/time-to-exit-beta/1480).

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain more specifically, the Writing community would like to shed the "beta" mislabel after *nearly a decade* and with a substantial body of quality content and high views.  Even if we aren't hitting 10 QPD, we are well past being *provisional* and would like the name of the site to reflect that even if we don't quality for other benefits.

Comment: [Your wish might be about to come true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322781/writing-se-clamours-for-graduation).

Comment: @panda yes, it is copied from 2017. Do you have any suggestions for a more original line to go in the archive page for 2018? – Yaakov Ellis♦ (I deleted the answer but Yaakov posted his own answer so you can reply there)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta)

Comment: Voting to leave this open. Politics and Space Exploration are still in beta...