# Unicorn Meta Zoo #4: What makes for a healthy community?

Tags: discussion, community, podcast, unicorn-meta-zoo

Welcome to the Unicorn Meta Zoo, a podcast by members of the Stack
Exchange community team. If you want to avoid spoilers, jump
[straight to the audio](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/healthy-communities.mp3).

#### Participants

[image: hairboat]
[image: Juan M]
[image: Jon Ericson]

We are talking about the attributes of a healthy community.

#### Links

- Our [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/),
  [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) and [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) sites.
- [Either "neesh" or "nitch" work for pronouncing niche.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/neesh-or-nitch)
- ["Big Dreams, Small Spaces"](https://www.netflix.com/title/80232852)
  is on my list of shows to watch . . . eventually. I believe Abby
  refers to season 2, episode 2 "Hitchin/Worthing".
- [We exercise our communal sense of humor at least once a year.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/12/15/winter-bash-2014/)
- [My proof God programs in Perl.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55823/ptij-perl-programming-in-the-torah/55826#55826)

#### Transcript

Some users have generously volunteered to transcribe episodes on
[the podcast wiki](https://github.com/unicorn-meta-zoo/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/wiki). I'm
extremely grateful for users who helped fill in some of
[the previous episode's transcript](https://github.com/unicorn-meta-zoo/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/wiki/How-do-we-grade-questions%3F-%5BTranscript%5D):

- bvanrijn
- ocæon
- MilkyWay90

#### Meta

This episode makes me think we need a real audio editor to get rid of
plosives. It's not an easy
[signal processing problem](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/human-speech-noise-filter).

#### What do you think?

[Take a listen](https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/unicorn-meta-zoo.github.io/episodes/healthy-communities.mp3) and respond in the answers below.

Comment: Thanks for the positive comments about Mi Yodeya!  FYI, we'll be ten years old at the end of this year, and are [marking the occasion in a Jewish way](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/472).  (Jon, if you want to join us -- the tractate named Avot should be pretty accessible, being more wisdom-literature and less halacha-details.)

Comment: Just asking but is this going on the Apple podcasts store-search-thing? I can’t find it and I’m subscribed. (I’m that 5star rating). Also, amazing podcast :)

Comment: @Eleeza: Thanks for the rating and the kinds words. As the podcast admin, I was able to schedule the feed to be rescanned, but it can take up to 24 hours. Hopefully it'll be sooner than that!

Comment: @Eleeza: Looks like [Apple podcasts](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/unicorn-meta-zoo/id1457917389) have the episode now.

Comment: "[...]we need a real audio editor to get rid of plosives. It's not an easy signal processing problem." Actually, it is. The trick is to process the signal before it reaches the microphone input stage. In other words... shell out the six lousy dollars for a pop filter. :P

Comment: This was really nice. I think us programmers and scientists and engineers are too technical at times to consider/give thought to about communities we are part of. With time we do develop social skills which are just enough to allow us to continue interacting with the outer world. :)

Comment: @jmbpiano: Yes, this is true. At the moment we all are using our headset mics, which isn't ideal. I think there are little foam covers that help reduce those sounds. It also helps to position the boom so that the mic isn't right in the line of breathing. I'll try to encourage better microphone discipline in the future.

Comment: God & Perl: [xkcd 224](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/224:_Lisp)

Comment: How about linking the Transcript users who helped

Comment: @PeterMortensen: [Nothing new under the sun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55823/971), I suppose.

Comment: @Lolpez I'm guessing you can just use the SE search users feature

Comment: Shouldnt the next one be out by now.. I am just being impatient..

Comment: @Haris: I'm posting one every third Tuesday. Maybe in the fall I can increase the pace a bit. But I don't want to run out of episodes over the summer!

Comment: @JonEricson Oh, Yes.. I don't know why I thought it was a weekly one.. My bad..

Answer (score 27):

## So why aren't beta sites being recognized as healthy communities?

[Writing.SE clamours for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/191265), as well as other beta sites like [BoardGames.SE](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) that have been in existence for *over 9 years*! There is no question that these are healthy communities (it certainly meets Jon Ericson's definition presented at the start of the podcast), and yet their requests to be recognized as such through graduation have been met with deafening silence.

The podcast talked extensively about creating healthy communities on new sites such as through Area 51, but not once was there discussion on how to maintain healthy communities on sites that have been around for dearly a decade, and how graduation is that recognition.

This is a huge oversight that needs to be addressed if Stack Exchange wants to keep its healthy communities around!

Comment: [I agree.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307988/1438) The main reason we didn't have that discussion is we don't have a good plan for how to provide recognition for community achievements. I wish I didn't have to be [a broken record on this](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1584/3306), but I don't have any solid answers just yet. :-(

Comment: @JonEricson You can understand our frustration on this; the two links you gave were from over a year ago. Has *any* progress been made towards this in the last year?

Comment: We're working toward a full site lifecycle that will give features to sites as they need them. There's a little bit of "perfect is the enemy of the good" syndrome here. But we have made some incremental changes such as [giving all sites elections when needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). We [just announced badge changes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/) that have been years in gestation, so there's hope for this too. ;-)