# Improve search – e.g. searching for "writing" should list results with "writing.se"

Tags: feature-request, search

This morning, I was writing an answer where I wanted to link to this question: [Writing.SE clamours for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322781/writing-se-clamours-for-graduation). I remembered three words in the title: 'writing' and 'clamours', the latter since I rarely encounter it. So I [search for `writing clamours`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=writing+clamours) and am perplexed to be staring at zero search results. Did the spelling change from [British to American English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clamour)? Nope, it turns out the Stack Exchange search engine treats 'Writing.SE' as one word; [searching for `writing.se clamours`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=writing.se+clamours) does yield the question I'm looking for.

I know the Stack Exchange search engine isn't meant to replace Google, with all its capabilities to correct spelling errors etc., but this should be rather easy to fix. The [tokenizer settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html) should be adjusted to split on dots/periods as well, just like they do right now on e.g. single quotes, as [this search example shows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=travel.se+-%22Travel.se%22).

Comment: [meta-tag:feature-request] [meta-tag:search] ... good luck with that.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Long.strings.with.no.spaces in titles overflow into the right column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379435/long-strings-with-no-spaces-in-titles-overflow-into-the-right-column)

Comment: @Justin not really, I think ... this is about how data is stored in the internal search engine backend (Elastic), not how it is shown.